# Is there a way to prevent the contentplaceholder's ID from affecting child ID's in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, contentplaceholder, sitefinity-4

If I have a placeholder that looks like this:

```
<asp:contentplaceholder ID="Body" runat="server"></asp:contentplaceholder>
```

And inside of it are several other elements that are `runat="server"` with ID properties, then I get something like this:

```
<span id="Body_T966DB943018">
  <div id="Body_T966DB943007_ctl00_ctl00_main"></div>
</span>
```

Is there a way to set up my `contentplaceholder` such that the output appears like this:

```
<span id="T966DB943018">
  <div id="T966DB943007_ctl00_ctl00_main"></div>
</span>
```

(notice the lack of the "Body_" in all generated IDs)

---

*If you want to know why I'm asking...*

I am using Sitefinity. By default, you can set up templates in a back end GUI. This was how the site was originally constructed.

The latter HTML structure is how the CMS has generated templates on the page. Initial construction of CSS and JS used these generated ID's. Now we have added a master template file, and we need to put a default `contentplaceholder` for Sitefinity's content.

I need to find a way to have this default placeholder (shown above with `ID="Body"` to not affect the ID's of its children.

Comment: You can set `ClientIDMode` property to `Static` for each child control (assuming you don't have any duplicate). [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti -- I was just looking at that property.. Unfortunately there are hundreds of child controls, and they are all automatically generated by the CMS, so this isn't an option.

Comment: I don't know if I have a good grasp of the situation here, but is this something where you could actually write out the html programmatically (ie: the old Classic ASP way)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There is a CMS that is generating the children, so I'd ideally need a solution in the parent element

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to redo your CSS and more appropriate as you can see it is very difficult to maintain those Ids

Comment: In addition to CSS, there may be JS also. And if it's a CMS system, then modifying those may not be straightforward.

Comment: I'm actually moving in this direction now. The problem is, as mason points out, that CSS and JS are sometimes in the CMS, so I'm trying to figure out in which DB tables might be hiding JS and CSS...

Comment: Sitefinity does not use those Ids for any JS purpose that i've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the behavior for the entire site you can do it in `web.config` by setting the [ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="Static" />
  </system.web>
<configuration>
```

---

Or at the page level.

```
<%@ Page ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```

---

Or at the individual control level.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

---

Keep in mind you'll need to ensure your Client ID's are unique to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I still need the children to be "Inherit" -- they are automatically generated by a CMS, and  I need their ID's to follow the pattern they seem to follow when I don't set my own .master file template. (I can't see what that is, as it's hidden in the codebase of proprietary software)

Comment: @tmsimont I don't think you can set it for a parent specifically but not have it affect the children. The children will still be inherit, but they will inherit from the parent. Meaning if you change the parent, the children will change.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case. I just tried it and the children are also affected. I am totally stumped. I don't know how the CMS is doing it. It looks like they created their own PlaceHolder extension called SitefinityPlaceHolder to use in place of ContentPlaceHolder, but when I try to use it in my .master file I get an error: "Could not find suitable place holder for required control."